# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class NewsModel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

the problem is a bit strange, I'm fighting with it since 2 days and before I post it as a bug just wanted to make sure this is not my mistake.

I have a clean CakePHP copy, I have a DB which is setup and Cake can connect to my DB with no problem.
in my DB I have a table named "news", and I have a controller with the following code:

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('News');

    public function news(){
        $news = $this->News->find('all');
        var_dump($news);
        die;
    }
}
```

as long as I dont create the model file for my table, this query runs successfully, but as soon as I create the following Model file (save as News.php in model folder) I see the error that comes after code:

```
<?php

class NewsModel extends AppModel {
}
```

the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class NewsModel in C:\...\cakephp\app\Model\News.php on line 4
```

I'm on the windows and running php > 5.2.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the class should be "News", without the model part.

```
class News extends AppModel { }
```

The docs show [examples](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html) everywhere. There may be confusion because the "News" Controller is called `NewsController` and the News Component, `NewsComponent`, but from the answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776652/controller-naming-convention), it's to avoid name collision (which gives you a do'h moment after you read it).

For future development, I find it easier just to bake the models/controllers/views and then delete what I don't need and change what I need changed.

Answer (score 0):

try using var $useTable = 'news'; in your model..
Hopefully your problem will solve.

Comment: the problem was obviously something else, but however just to give a hint, I had already tried that and this made no difference ;)

Answer (score -1):

Model should be singular to better fit cake convetions

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class New extends AppModel {

}
?>

$news = $this->New->find('all');
```

Comment: but "new" is not singular of "news" ([forum reference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1067564)) :S

Comment: Plus "new" is a reserved keyword in PHP and will lead to a parse error when used as a class name.